# How link OpenSSL's libcrypto.a to Firebreath plugin in XCode

Tags: xcode, cmake, static-linking, firebreath

I am newbie. I have compiled OpenSSL's libcrypto.a in shell, but could not link it to my Firebreath plugin.
I have added in CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(${CURPROJECT} /path/to/libcrypto.a)
```

But CMake gives error:

*Cannot specify link libraries for target
"/path/to/libcrypto.a" which is not build by this project*

I am using MacOSX 10.9, XCode 5.1.1, FireBreath 1.7, OpenSSL 1.0.1i.

Please explain to me, how could I link libcrypto.a to my plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you already tested the "experimental" built-in openssl support described here:

[Firebreath libraries](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Libraries)

Comment: The statement `add_firebreath_library(openssl)` has solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you're getting indicates that it thinks you're trying to add a link library for the project `/path/to/libcrypto.a`, *not* that you are trying to add the link library `/path/to/libcrypto.a` to the project `$(CURPROJECT)`.

This might be because you need to do `${CURPROJECT}` (cmake variables use `{}` not `()`).  It could also be that the variable `CURPROJECT` isn't defined.

Your command is correct, but the parameters you are passing into it are not.  You might also consider using find_library to find libcrypto.a.

Of course, with Mac OS you should already have openssl available, so you shouldn't need to specify the path.  Also, as @hasa mentioned, you are probably better off just using the firebreath openssl stuff, which is experimental but really just on windows -- mac OS it just uses the existing ones.  It's only marked experimental because I'm not willing to provide support for the windows binaries.

Comment: First, let me express my gratitude for your great project. And I am sorry for misprinting () instead of {} in the question. The statement `add_firebreath_library(openssl)` has solved my problem. Thank you.